# Script to plot blackbody radiation at different wavelengths

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that calculates the Planck function, given a wavelength and a specific temperature. Then, I want to plot out the range of wavelengths emitted at temperatures of 290K, 1250K, 1800K, 2600K, 5000K, and 6000K. I am using Studio and I have never plotted this before. I will also need to plot lambda max for each of these temperatures using wien's displacement law. Is there a basic script that I can use to help me plot this? I don't have much experience with R or programming softwares.

I am using Plancks equation to solve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.